# symfony 4 base twig method(s) override

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4, twig-extension

How to override path() method for twig, when autowire is enabled?
For example:

```
class ExampleRoutingExtension extends RoutingExtension
{
    public function getPath($name, $parameters = array(), $relative = false)
    {
        return '/testEndpoint';
    }
}
```

there is no problem with autowiring with this class(constructor creates object), but getPath() method does not overrides parent getPath()

Comment: I'm wondering what's the purpose of this? If you're trying to overwrite the request base url - you could try [Configuring the Request Context Globally](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/request_context.html#configuring-the-request-context-globally).

Comment: I want to drag all get parameters for every href.. so it will be cool to override path(), and add get params inside it

Answer (score 0):

Create your Twig extension :

```
class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('path', [$this, 'path']),
        ];
    }

    public function path(string $name, array $parameters = array(), bool $relative = false): string
    {
        return '/testEndpoint';
    }
}
```

And enabled with services.yml :

```
App\Twig\YourExtension:
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

You can inject service (example : routing) in `__construct()`

Comment: yes, this is one of the easiest variants, but the main idea of overriding path() - do not modify views(twig files)

Comment: upd: this method do not overrides path(), twig calls his own path() method

Comment: Not in symfony 4 (I tested). What is your version ?

Comment: ver - Symfony 4.0.4